# What is the difference between linear lagrange interpolation and defining secant lines?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, lagrange-interpolation

From what I am noticing, linear Lagrange interpolation just looks like another way to find a secant line given two points.

What is the difference?

Comment: It happens quite often that you get the same solution or part of a solution from different situations. This is even more pronounced if the search space is limited by order, degree or some other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No difference whatsoever. For univariate data, the first order interpolating polynomial on distinct points $ x_0 < x_1$ is indeed the secant line passing through those points.